# Full feature Linux scheduler

Tags: cron, php, scheduling, web

The scheduler cron processes outputs of programs only sending them via mails or writing them in files. So these outputs can't be assigned for example to a PHP variable (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040627/outputs-ignored-in-cron-jobs)).

Is there another scheduler which permits to run a PHP program (which updates a database) every 10 minutes ?

Answer (score 2):

Cron only executes commands, you can make it execute a binary or a script as you wish, including a PHP script if you feel like it.

You could technically execute a script that would use curl to GET an URL, and include your variable in the URL, or you could POST to an URL and add your variable to a header.

Comment: OK but it's approximately as cumbersome as writing the content of a variable in a file.

Comment: Cron can execute a PHP script every 10 minutes as you asked.

Comment: Yes, but when doing so, if a PHP script trys to get the output of another PHP program, you get the following error: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)